# how to alert the value attribute of a selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I want to alert the value of a "value" attribute of a select-option box

```
<select class="form-control" id="selet-city" required >
    <option selected disabled>Please select a City</option>
    <option vlaue="dsfsdfsd">bangalore</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
</select>
```

I tried this:-

```
alert($('#selet-city option:selected').attr('value'));
```

Comment: correct the spell of value

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($("#selet-city option:selected").val())
```

You can check it with

```
$("#selet-city").change( function(){alert($("#selet-city option:selected").val());})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it

```
<select class="form-control" id="selet-city" required >
<option selected disabled>Please select a City</option>
<option vlaue="dsfsdfsd">bangalore</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
```

```
$("#selet-city").change( function(){alert($("#selet-city option:selected").val());})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/badarrashdi/jkass3hw/